# R - compare rows consecutively in two data frames and return a value

Tags: r, if-statement, compare, dataframe

I have the following two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(month=c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3"),
             temp=c("10","15","16","25","13","17","20","5","16","25","30","37"))


df2 <-  data.frame(period=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3"),
              max_temp=c("9","13","16","18","30","37","38","39","10","15","16","25","30","32","8","10","12","14","16","18","19","25","28","30","35","40"),
              group=c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","4","4","5","5","5","5","5","6","6","6","7","7","7","7","8","8"))
```

I would like to:

1. Consecutively for each row, check if the value in the `month` column in `df1` matches that in the `period` column of `df2`, *i.e.* `df1$month == df2$period`.
2. If step 1 is not TRUE, *i.e.* `df1$month != df2$period`, then repeat step 1 and compare the value in `df1` with the value in the next row of `df2`, and so forth until `df1$month == df2$period`.
3. If `df1$month == df2$period`, check if the value in the `temp` column of `df1` is less than or equal to that in the `max_temp` column of `df2`, *i.e.* `df1$temp <= df$max_temp`.
4. If `df1$temp <= df$max_temp`, return value in that row for the `group` column in `df2` and add this value to `df1`, in a new column called `"new_group"`.
5. If step 3 is not TRUE, *i.e.* `df1$temp > df$max_temp`, then go back to step 1 and compare the same row in `df1` with the next row in `df2`.

An example of the output data frame I'd like is:

```
df3 <- data.frame(month=c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3"),
             temp=c("10","15","16","25","13","17","20","5","16","25","30","37"),
             new_group=c("1","1","1","2","3","4","4","5","6","7","7","8"))
```

I've been playing around with the `ifelse` function and need some help or re-direction. Thanks!

Comment: do you purposefully have your data as strings?

Comment: The data files are actually tab-delimited text files which I upload into R as data frames using read.table. As an R newbie, I wasn't aware the data was in strings.

Comment: the quotes around the numbers tells you you've got strings.  Also, be careful for strings masquerading as factors, which you will have is `read.table(.... stringsAsFactors=TRUE)` (which annoyingly is the default)

Comment: The data.frame code I've given is simply an attempt to reproduce the data frames I'm working with in R. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the procedure for computing `new_group` hard to follow as stated. As I understand it, you're trying to create a variable called `new_group` in `df1`. For row `i` of `df1`, the `new_group` value is the `group` value of the first row in `df2` that:

1. Is indexed `i` or higher
2. Has a `period` value matching `df1$month[i]`
3. Has a `max_temp` value no less than `df1$temp[i]`

I approached this by using `sapply` called on the row indices of `df1`:

```
fxn = function(idx) {
  # Potentially matching indices in df2
  pm = idx:nrow(df2)

  # Matching indices in df2
  m = pm[df2$period[pm] == df1$month[idx] &
         as.numeric(as.character(df1$temp[idx])) <=
         as.numeric(as.character(df2$max_temp[pm]))]

  # Return the group associated with the first matching index
  return(df2$group[m[1]])
}
df1$new_group = sapply(seq(nrow(df1)), fxn)
df1
#    month temp new_group
# 1      1   10         1
# 2      1   15         1
# 3      1   16         1
# 4      1   25         2
# 5      2   13         3
# 6      2   17         4
# 7      2   20         4
# 8      3    5         5
# 9      3   16         6
# 10     3   25         7
# 11     3   30         7
# 12     3   37         8
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful code. The values for new_group are not computed, but simply the value of df2$group placed into the df1$new_group column. Hope this makes it clearer. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, the code I posted does this. It looks like you're pretty new to SO and haven't been accepting the good answers you've received on your previous questions. If my solution or @RicardoSaporta's solution solves your problem, remember to accept it by checking the green check box.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1, key="month")
dt2 <- data.table(df2, key="period")

## add a row index
dt1[, rn1 := seq(nrow(dt1))]

dt3 <- 
unique(dt1[dt2, allow.cartesian=TRUE][, new_group := group[min(which(temp <= max_temp))], by="rn1"], by="rn1")

## Keep only the columns you want
dt3[, c("month", "temp", "max_temp", "new_group"), with=FALSE]

    month temp max_temp new_group
 1:     1    1       19         1
 2:     1    3       19         1
 3:     1    4       19         1
 4:     1    7       19         1
 5:     2    2        1         3
 6:     2    5        1         3
 7:     2    6        1         4
 8:     3   10       18         5
 9:     3    4       18         5
10:     3    7       18         5
11:     3    8       18         5
12:     3    9       18         5
```